# compare one column in two tables and fetch orders which are not same in both the tables

Tags: sql, hana

Compare two tables using field /bic/zcnvdlpc, and fetch /bic/zsorhdr(which is  key for both the tables) which are not equal.

[image: sampleData]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow , Please make sure you are providing enough in question for someone to help you. Always keep in mind that you are asking someone to HELP you with the problem you have.

Comment: Please don't rely on images to express your question, try describing the problem using words. Sample data should be in a reusable format such as inserts or a text table. For this question what is missing in particular is how the 2 tables can be joined, is there any field in common between those 2 tables? (does not appear in the image)